# Series expansion for $e^{\sin x}$ and coefficient comparison

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am looking for a way to expand the function $e^{\sin x}$ into Taylor series without employing the cumbersome Taylor formula and come across this thread:
[Finding the Maclaurin series of $e^{\sin x}$ by comparing coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015698/finding-the-maclaurin-series-of-e-sin-x-by-comparing-coefficients)

[image]

I understand almost everything of Bernard's answer except the red underlied part. How do you obtain
$(c-\dfrac{1}{2})x^2+(d-\frac{b}{2})x^3$ and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are simply combining coefficients by exponent. That is when you multiply out the polynomial you'll have $c$ a coefficient of $x^2$ and $-\frac{a}{2}$ a coefficient. So $$cx^2 -\frac{a}{2}x^2 =(c-\frac{a}{2})x^2.$$
And so on of course.

Answer (score 1):

For the $x^2$ term it seems there is a typo indeed we should have

$$cx^2-\frac12 ax^2 =\left(c-\frac a2\right)x^2$$

then

$$ dx^3-\frac12b x^3=\left(d-\frac b2\right)x^3$$

and

$$1\cdot ex^4+\left(-\frac {x^2}2\right) \cdot cx^2+\frac {x^4}{24} \cdot a=\left(e-\frac c 2+\frac a{24}\right)x^4$$

and finally

$$1\cdot fx^5+\left(-\frac {x^2}2\right) \cdot dx^3+\frac {x^4}{24} \cdot bx=\left(f-\frac d 2+\frac b{24}\right)x^5$$

Comment: what about $(e-\frac{c}{2}+\frac{a}{24})x^4$ Where does the $\frac{a}{24}$ and $\frac{c}{2}$ come from? I don't understand the part for $x^5$ as well.

Comment: The firtst term comes from $1\cdot ex^4$ the second one from $-\frac {x^2}2 \cdot cx^2$ and the third from $\frac {x^4}{24} \cdot a$.

Comment: What about the third, fourth and fifth term?

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification.

Comment: @JamesWarthington You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Note:
this is one of my
nothing-original-here answers.

If
$g(x)
=e^{f(x)}
$,
where
$f(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_kx^k
$,
then
$g'(x)
=f'(x)e^{f(x)}
=f'(x)g(x)
$
and
$f'(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ka_kx^{k-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}
$.

Assuming
$g(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n
$,
then
$g'(x)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nb_nx^{n-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)b_{n+1}x^{n}
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)b_{n+1}x^{n}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{k=0}^m (k+1)a_{k+1}b_{m-k}\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{k=0}^m (m-k+1)a_{m-k+1}b_{k}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$(n+1)b_{n+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k+1)a_{n-k+1}b_{k}
$.

This gives the recursion
$b_{n+1}
=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n (n-k+1)a_{n-k+1}b_{k}
$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge1$, by the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials, we have
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\operatorname{e}^{\sin x}\bigr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{e}^{\sin x} B_{n,k}\biggl(\cos x,-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\dotsc, \sin\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
&\to \sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}\biggl(1,0,-1,0,\dotsc, \sin\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr), \quad x\to0\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr] \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!!} \sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^q\binom{k}{q}(2q-k)^n.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we obtain
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{e}^{\sin x}
=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^n \biggl[\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2\biggr] \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!!} \sum_{q=0}^k(-1)^q\binom{k}{q}(2q-k)^n\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}.
\end{equation*}

References

1. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.