# What is wrong with my series expansion of $e^{\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

[Finding the Maclaurin series of $e^{\sin x}$ by comparing coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3015698/finding-the-maclaurin-series-of-e-sin-x-by-comparing-coefficients)

In this thread, Bernard showed how to find the Maclaurin series of $e^{\sin(x)}$ by differentiating it to give $\cos(x)e^{\sin(x)}$. I try to emulate this method to find the series expansion of $e^{\cos(x)}$. I differentiate it to obtain $-\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}$.

The series for $-\sin(x)=-x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}-\dfrac{x^5}{5!}+\dfrac{x^7}{7!}-\dfrac{x^9}{9!}+\dfrac{x^{11}}{11!}-\dfrac{x^{13}}{13!}+O(x^{15})$

If $e^{\cos(x)}$ has a series representation, suppose that it has the form:

$a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4+fx^5+gx^6+O(x^7)$

Differentiate this series we have:

$-\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}= 0+b+2cx+3dx^2+4ex^3+5fx^4+6gx^5+7hx^6+8ix^7\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$

Multiply $e^{\cos(x)}$ with $-\sin(x)$, we obtain the series:

$a+(b-a)x+(c-b)x^2+(d-c+\dfrac{a}{6})x^3+(e-d+\dfrac{b}{6})x^4+(f+\dfrac{a}{120}+\dfrac{c}{6})x^5+(g+f+\dfrac{d}{6}-\dfrac{b}{120})x^6+O(x^7)\tag{2}\label{eq:2}$

Equate (\ref{eq:1}) and (\ref{eq:2}), we have:

$b+2cx+3dx^2+4ex^3+5fx^4+6gx^5+7hx^6+8ix^7=a+(b-a)x+(c-b)x^2+(d-c+\dfrac{a}{6})x^3+(e-d+\dfrac{b}{6})x^4+(f+\dfrac{a}{120}+\dfrac{c}{6})x^5+(g+f+\dfrac{d}{6}-\dfrac{b}{120})x^6+O(x^7)$

Two infinite series are equal if all their coefficients are equal to each other:

So equating the coefficients of the series on the left hand side with the right hand side, we have:
$a=b$. When $x=0$,$e^{\cos(x)}=e, f(x)=a$ implies $a=e$ and $b=e$

Here is what starts to break down completely:

$b-a=2c$

$c-b=3d$

$d-c+\dfrac{a}{6}=4e$

$e-d+\dfrac{b}{6}=5f$

$f+\dfrac{a}{120}+\dfrac{c}{6}=6g$

$g-f+\dfrac{d}{6}-\dfrac{b}{120}=7h$

From there, I got $c=0$, which is a wrong answer.

Wolfram gives the series representation of $e^{\cos(x)}$ as followed:

$e-\dfrac{ex^2}{2}+\dfrac{ex^4}{6}+\dfrac{31e^6}{720}+...$

Why does this method work for Bernard's answer to $e^{\sin(x)}$ but fail to work for $e^{\cos(x)}$? What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: when you multiply $e^{\cos x}$ with $-\sin x$, don't you get $(a+bx+cx^2+...)(-x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}...)=(-ax-bx^2...)$ rather than $a+(b-a)x...$?

Comment: @Bernard: Hi Bernard! I thought you group terms together? I mean finding all terms that is multiplied with the same order of $x$, so for example: You find all terms that is multiplied with $x$. In this case, $bx$ and $-ax$ are all terms that is multiplied with $x$, see your answer on the other thread, that's what I thought I should do.

Comment: Actually, I'm not  the author of the answer you lonked to. I only edited it, probably to fix some typos. This being said, you may greatly simplify  your computations observing that $\mathrm e^{\cos x}$  is an even function and therefore has only terms of even degree.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply $e^{\cos x}$ with $-\sin x$ to get $\left(a+bx+cx^2+...\right)\left(-x+\dfrac{x^3}{3!}...\right)=-ax-bx^2...,$

and then set $-ax-bx^2...=b+2cx+3dx^2+...$ to get $b=0, -a=2c, d=0,...$

so $e^{\cos x}=a-\dfrac a2 x^2...$, and from evaluation at $x=0$ note that $a=e$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you group all terms together. Your mistake is you are grouping terms that don't exist along with the terms that do exist.

There is no constant term when you multiply $-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\cdots$ with another MacLaurin series, so your constant term $a$ should not exist. There is only one term in $x$, which is $-ax.$ There is no $bx$ term, because (unlike the expansion of $\cos x$) there is no constant term $1$ in the expansion of $\sin x$.

If you're having trouble keeping track of what terms should be in the product of two series, long multiplication may help:

\begin{eqnarray}
-xe^{\cos(x)}
 &=& -ax&-&bx^2&-&cx^3&-&dx^4&-&ex^5&-&fx^6&-&gx^7&-&hx^8&-\cdots\\
\frac{x^3}{3!}e^{\cos(x)}
 &=& &&&&\frac a{3!}x^3&+&\frac b{3!}x^4&+&\frac c{3!}x^5&+&\frac d{3!}x^6&+&\frac e{3!}x^7&+&\frac f{3!}x^8&+\cdots\\
-\frac{x^5}{5!}e^{\cos(x)}
 &=& &&&&&&&-&\frac a{5!}x^5&-&\frac b{5!}x^6&-&\frac c{5!}x^7&-&\frac d{5!}x^8&-\cdots\\
\frac{x^7}{7!}e^{\cos(x)}
 &=& &&&&&&&&&&&&\frac a{7!}x^7&-&\frac b{7!}x^8&-\cdots\\
\end{eqnarray}

Adding up the columns,

\begin{multline}
\left(-x+\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}-O(x^{9})\right)e^{\cos(x)} = \\
-ax -bx^2 + \left(\frac a{3!}-c\right)x^3 + \left(\frac b{3!}-d\right)x^4\\
+ \left(\frac c{3!}-\frac a{5!}-e\right)x^5
+ \left(\frac d{3!}-\frac b{5!}-f\right)x^6\\
+ \left(\frac a{7!}-\frac c{5!}+\frac e{e!}-g\right)x^7
+ \left(\frac b{7!}-\frac d{5!}+\frac f{e!}-h\right)x^8 + \cdots.
\end{multline}

You then get $b=0,$ $2c = -a,$ $3d = -b = 0,$
$4e = \frac a{3!}-c = \frac23a,$ $5f = \frac b{3!}-d = 0,$
$6g = \frac c{3!}-\frac a{5!}-e = -\frac{31}{120}a,$ and so forth.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have another method that use Cauchy product, I am going to employ that method since it allows me to correctly produce all coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\ge1$, by the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials, we have
\begin{align*}
\bigl(\operatorname{e}^{\cos x}\bigr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{e}^{\cos x} B_{n,k}\biggl(-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\cos x,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
&\to \operatorname{e}\sum_{k=1}^n B_{n,k}\biggl(0,-1,0,1,\dotsc, \cos\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr), \quad x\to0\\
&=\operatorname{e} \biggl(\cos\frac{n\pi}2\biggr) \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n.
\end{align*}
Consequently, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{e}^{\cos x}
&=\operatorname{e} +\operatorname{e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\biggl(\cos\frac{n\pi}2\biggr)\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n\Biggr]\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\operatorname{e} +\operatorname{e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n \Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{2n}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.
\end{align*}

References

1. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.